# How to pass class variables to Parameterized Decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

I've a decorator which takes parameters.

```
def decorator(abc):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(abc) # prints base class variable
            # do something
            return True
        return wrapper
    return inner
```

I've Child-Parent Classes as follow:-

```
class ABC():

    abc = 1

    @decorator(abc)
    def func(self):
        return True


class DEF(ABC):

    abc = 2


obj = DEF()
print(obj.func())
```

The problem that I'm facing is while passing child class variable to the decorator, it still takes the base class variable.

**How do I pass the child class variable to the decorator?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your decorator is being passed a concrete value at definition time of the base class and its function. There is no attribute access whatsoever and the function does not get magically redefined and redecorated with a new value in the derived class. 
It also makes little sense to pass a class attribute to a method decorator in the first place as the method has dynamic access to it via the passed instance anyway. You can do the much simpler:

```
def decorator(func):
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.__class__.abc)  # actually prints the class attribute
        # do something
        return True
    return inner

class ABC(object):
    abc = 1

    @decorator
    def func(self):
        return True

>>> a = ABC()
>>> a.func()
1
True
>>> b = DEF()
>>> b.func()
2
True
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to considere that what you want to process in the decorator is the run time value of an attribute. Then you just pass the attribute name and use it at run time. That is enough, because a method gets its object as its first parameter:

```
def decorator(attr):
    def inner(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print(getattr(args[0], attr)) # prints current attribute
            # do something
            return True
        return wrapper
    return inner

class ABC():

    abc = 1

    @decorator('abc')
    def func(self):
        return True

class DEF(ABC):

    abc = 2

obj = DEF()
obj.func()
```

gives as expected:

```
2
True
```

Answer (score 0):

One other solution could be to override the method in DEF, since according to DEF.__mro__, since python cannot find the method declared in DEF, it will go to parent class and find it there, passing in ABC's class attribute.

Output of DEF.__mro__:

```
(__main__.DEF, __main__.ABC, object)
```

A proposed solution:

```
class ABC(object):
    abc = 1

    @decorator(abc)
    def func(self):
        return True

class DEF(ABC):
    abc = 2

    @decorator(abc)
    def func(self):
        return True
```